# Finding new Sonar issues with SonarLint for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

Is there any way to retrieve only the new Sonar issues brought by a SCM change with the SonarLint plugin for IntelliJ? 
Thank you.

Comment: On the **Report** tab, there's a button labeled **Analyze VCS Change Files**. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep I so that, but I'm afraid it reports all the issues in those files and not only the new ones.

Comment: Then the answer is no, currently there isn't a way. (See you my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

On the **Report** tab, there's a button labeled **Analyze VCS Changed Files**,
which will analyze only the files that were modified since the last commit.
The analysis report will include all issues in these files,
not only the new issues.

Currently SonarLint doesn't have a feature to show only the new issues in these files. This sounds like an interesting feature. Perhaps you could suggest it on the [community forum](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/suggestions/features).